# Is there a way to decompile multiple android apk at the same time?

Tags: android, decompiler, smali, apktool

I'm currently doing project that needs .smali file from android app. In order to get .smali file i have to decompile android app. Thus, someone recommends me to use apktool. Unfortunately, apktool only can decompile an android app at one time. I need to decompile a lot of apps ( more than 4000). it will waste my time if I decompile it one by one. So, is there a way to decompile multiple android apk at the same time? or If you can recommend me tools that will help me get .smali files from multiple app faster? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly easy to do with the standard "find" tool.

```
cd directory_with_apks
find . -iname "*.apk" -exec apktool d -o {}_out {} \;
```